# setcookie in google chrome not working unless set to more than 5 days

Tags: php, google-chrome, setcookie

I have a weird problem with the php function "setcookie". When I set a cookie for 1 hour, chrome is not getting the cookie, but if I set a cookie for more than 5 days, it is working.

I have tried to find a answer to this problem without success

Comment: Which version of chrome are you using? There were some bugs in the past related to cookies. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=126397 How about Firefox & IE? Are they working?

Comment: I would check the response headers setting the cookies. If they are correct in both cases, you know it is not your code but Chrome.